# Applying angular momentum operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, wavefunction

How are the algebraic steps to applied the angular momentum operator defined as: $$\hat{L}=-i\hbar[r\times\nabla]$$ to $$\Psi=a~ \psi_{431}$$ where the $\psi_{nlm}$ are the eigenfunctions of the time independent Schrödinger equation for the hydrogen atom.

---

**Note 1 :**
For the $\:\psi_{nlm}\:$ eigenfunction
\begin{align}
H\,| \psi_{nlm}\rangle        & = E_{n} | \psi_{nlm}\rangle \tag{01}\\
L^{2}\,| \psi_{nlm}\rangle  & = \ell\left(\ell+1\right)\hbar^{2} | \psi_{nlm}\rangle \tag{02}\\
L_{z}\,| \psi_{nlm}\rangle  & = m\hbar | \psi_{nlm}\rangle \tag{03}
\end{align}
**Note 2 :**
For information (not necessary)
\begin{align}
 E_{n}    & = \dfrac{E_{0}}{n^2}\tag{04a}\\
E_{0}  & = \textrm{ground state energy}=-13.6~\textrm{eV} \tag{04b}
\end{align}

Comment: Do you not know how to calculate a gradient and cross product?

Comment: what is $a$? The hydrogen wavefunctions are eigenfunctions of $\hat{L}$

Comment: a it is a real constant.

Comment: @BySymmetry $\psi_{431}$ is an eigenstate of $L_z$, and ICAM is asking about the effect of the vector angular momentum operator. That said, there are clear rules for the interaction of each angular momentum component operator with eigenstates of $L_z$, and these are explained in detail in any suitable QM textbook.

Comment: **Note 1 :**
For the $\:\psi_{nlm}\:$ eigenstate 
\begin{align}
H\,| \psi_{nlm}\rangle        & = E_{n} | \psi_{nlm}\rangle \tag{01}\\
L^{2}\,| \psi_{nlm}\rangle  & = \ell\left(\ell+1\right)\hbar^{2} | \psi_{nlm}\rangle \tag{02}\\
L_{z}\,| \psi_{nlm}\rangle  & = m\hbar | \psi_{nlm}\rangle \tag{03}
\end{align}
**Note 2 :**
For information (not necessary)
\begin{align}
 E_{n}    & =\dfrac{E_{0}}{n^2}\tag{04a}\\
E_{0}  & = \textrm{ground state energy}=-13.6 eV \tag{04b}
\end{align}

Comment: @honeste_vivere :
My above comment was previously an edit of the question. You rejected it because _This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer._  I really don't understand how this edit  addresses the author or how this should be an answer.

Comment: @Frobenius completely agree with your answer, and this $$\hat{L}\psi_{nlm}=?$$. Sorry but I do not see the solution.

Comment: Sorry, my comment is not an answer. It was an edit to your question to explain what you mean as eigenfunction $\:\psi_{nlm}\:$, an edit rejected by user honeste_vivere. See my 2nd comment above.

Comment: The wavefunction is not an eigenfunction of $\hat{L}$.  It's an eigenfunction of $L^2$ and $L_z$.  It's really unclear what your question is.  If you want to do the algebra, then learn how to take the gradient of a function and the cross product.  You need to do the work yourself. There's not a conceptual question here.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\:\mathbf{L}\:$ the vector angular momentum operator 
$$
\mathbf{L} =\left( L_{x},L_{y},L_{z} \right)
\tag{01}
$$
The eigenfunction $ | \psi_{n\ell m}\rangle\:$  is a common eigenstate of  $\:H,L^{2},L_{z}$ and more precisely for our case is  an eigenstate of  $\:L_{z}\:$ 
with eigenvalue $\:m\:$, so
$$
L_{z}| \psi_{n\ell m}\rangle  =m\hbar|\psi_{n\ell m}\rangle \quad \Longrightarrow \quad L_{z}| \psi_{431}\rangle  =\hbar|\psi_{431}\rangle
\tag{02}
$$
Now, taking advantage of the definitions and properties of the **raising** and **lowering** operators we have

$$
L_{\pm}| \psi_{n\ell m}\rangle =\left(L_{x} \pm i L_{y}\right)| \psi_{n\ell m}\rangle=\hbar \sqrt{\ell\left( \ell+1\right)-m\left( m \pm1\right)}| \psi_{n\ell \left( m\pm1\right)}\rangle
\tag{03}
$$
giving for our $ | \psi_{431}\rangle\:$
$$
L_{\pm}| \psi_{431}\rangle =\left(L_{x} \pm i L_{y}\right)| \psi_{431}\rangle=\hbar \sqrt{12-1\left( 1 \pm 1\right)}\,| \psi_{43\left( 1\pm1\right)}\rangle
\tag{04}
$$
so
\begin{align}
L_{+}| \psi_{431}\rangle & =\left(L_{x} + i L_{y}\right)| \psi_{431}\rangle=\hbar \sqrt{10}\,| \psi_{432}\rangle
\tag{05+}\\
L_{-}| \psi_{431}\rangle  & =\left(L_{x}- i L_{y}\right)| \psi_{431}\rangle=\hbar \sqrt{12}\,| \psi_{430}\rangle
\tag{05 - }
\end{align}
From (5$\pm$)
\begin{align}
L_{x}| \psi_{431}\rangle & =\:\:\:\dfrac{1}{2}\:\:\,\left(L_{+} + L_{-}\right)| \psi_{431}\rangle=\:\:\:\:\hbar \,\biggl(\sqrt{\dfrac{5}{2}}|\psi_{432}\rangle+\sqrt{3}|\psi_{430}\rangle\biggr)
\tag{06x}\\
L_{y}|\psi_{431}\rangle & = -\dfrac{1}{2}i\left(L_{+} - L_{-}\right)| \psi_{431}\rangle=-i\hbar \,\biggl(\sqrt{\dfrac{5}{2}}|\psi_{432}\rangle-\sqrt{3}|\psi_{430}\rangle\biggr)
\tag{06y}
\end{align}
and finally
$$
\boxed {\bbox[#FFFF88,8px]{\mathbf{L}|\psi_{431}\rangle =\hbar\Bigg[ \biggl(\sqrt{\dfrac{5}{2}}|\psi_{432}\rangle+\sqrt{3}|\psi_{430}\rangle\biggr),-i\,\biggl(\sqrt{\dfrac{5}{2}}|\psi_{432}\rangle-\sqrt{3}|\psi_{430}\rangle\biggr),|\psi_{431}\rangle\Biggr]}}
\tag{07}
$$